# tm_term_score error for term pairs and phrases

Tags: text, tm, scoring, phrase

Trying to score terms phrases or terms pairs as 1 or 0 for text in rows using tm_term_score  get this error:

```
c1 <- Corpus(VectorSource(r1))
inspect(c1)
inspect(c1[2])
cleanR1 <- tm_map(c1, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1, content_transformer(tolower))
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1, removeWords, c("re", "ve", "ahha"))   
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1, removePunctuation)
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1, removeSpecialChars)
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1, removeNumbers)
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1,removeWords,stopwords('en'))
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1,stripWhitespace)
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1,stemDocument)
cleanR1 <- tm_map(cleanR1, PlainTextDocument)

tm_term_score(cleanR1, terms, FUN = slam::row_sum)
```

Error in UseMethod("tm_term_score", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'tm_term_score' applied to an object of class "c('VCorpus', 'Corpus')"

> str(terms)
>    chr [1:61] "Helping learn" "Helping grow" .

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `PlainTextDocument`, a term frequency as returned by `termFreq`, or a `TermDocumentMatrix` to the first argument of `tm_term_score` rather than a corpus.

Example using a term document matrix:

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanR1)
tm_term_score(tdm, terms, FUN = slam::row_sum)
```

See the documentation, `?tm::tm_term_score`

Comment: I am using a TermDocumentMatrix, but still getting the same error. tdf_arrTerms <- TermDocumentMatrix(vectCorpus)
sapply(tdf_arrTerms, tm_term_score, terms_in_General_Inquirer_categories("Positiv"))

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `sapply`, just pass your terms directly to `tm_term_score`

Comment: yeah. Figured that out. the sapply sample was provided in the tm docs. thanks